# grep each line from a file in another file

Tags: shell, grep

i have to grep  one each line from a file and count the occurences in another file . the contents of two template files are:

template_service:

```
CO_SERVICE_SVCID268435463;Main Service
CO_FT_NON_BESTOWED_SVCID268435464;Bestowed Service
CO_SFT_NON_BESTOWED_SVCID268435465;Non Bestowed Service
```

template1(made out of first file itself) :

```
CO_SERVICE_SVCID268435463
CO_FT_NON_BESTOWED_SVCID268435464
CO_SFT_NON_BESTOWED_SVCID268435465
```

which contains search string(ie each different line).
and there is another file(text3.txt) with 1,00,000+ lines which contains either of the three above mentioned strings(the content of template_service may also vary,it is not fixed).

this is the code i have written:

```
file="/somepath/etc/template_service.txt"

while IFS= read -r line
do

                echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f1 >>template1.txt
                echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f2 >>template2.txt
                grep -c -f template1.txt text3.txt >>final_count.txt  <--problematic statement showing incorrect count

done <"$file"
```

This should count the occurance of each line from file one in text3.txt and print the result in final_count.txt
This is showing the output as :

```
60000
120000
180000
```

But the output should be :

```
60000
60000
60000
```

Why is it adding the previous sum as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it adding the previous sum as well?

Because of this:

```
echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f1 >>template1.txt
```

Changing it to:

```
echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f1 >template1.txt
```

should fix the issue.  Using `>>` causes the line to be *appended* to the file causing the previous count to be added to the result.

Comment: you misunderstood my question...there is no problem in echo "$line" | cut -d';' -f1 >>template1.txt line..the problem is in grep -c -f template1.txt text3.txt >>final_count.txt which is showing the wrong output..

Comment: @subodh1989 I don't think so.  The problem is that while reading `template_service.txt`, you keep on appending to what you've read so far.  So `grep -f` would match the previously added + newly added patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You always append to the `templateX.txt` files (you use `>>`).

So the second time grep is called it uses the first two lines from template_service.txt, and all three for the third time.

Instead try using `>` to write the `templateX.txt` files.